# How do you load an external web app with Cordova 4.0?

Tags: ios, cordova

We're using Cordova ~3.9 to load an external web app via the `<content>` tag in the `config.xml` file like so:
`<content src="http://10.1.1.1:3000"/>`

When updating to Cordova 4.0+ we can no longer load an external app via this method; the app loads nothing.

I've looked into the whitelist changes for Cordova 4.0 and tried using the `<access>`, `<allow-intent>`, and `<allow-navigation>` tags to allow access to the external origin without success.

Functional differences: 
3.9 - Loads external url as source of Cordova app
4.0+ - No page is loaded, app shows blank screen

How do you load an external site with Cordova 4.0+?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The security policy in Apache Cordova has changed drastically from Cordova 5.0 which does not allow you to access external URL without whitelist plugin.

As far as I know, if you are intended to access externally hosted web application inside Cordova application, better check out [hosted webapp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-hostedwebapp)

The plugin enables using content hosted in a web site inside a Cordova application by providing a manifest that describes the site. Also it lets you use the features of Cordova plugins too.

Answer (score 0):

I do this, but I have in the index.html file in the project load load the website with

```
top.location.href = "https://mywebapp.com";
```

I'm using Phonegap 5.5.2. In config.xml, I have

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

In the plist on Mac, I have Allow Arbitrary Loads set to YES.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it works on iOS Cordova 4.2.1 (the current version as of September 2016):

```
<allow-navigation href="[your url, wildcards, etc]" />
```

I put this in the iOS platform section of config.xml.

I'm guessing the problem you were having is an issue that was fixed with a newer version of iOS Cordova since you posted.

People have been saying "Don't use Cordova this way" for years, and they've been wrong for years.  It works just fine, and Apple doesn't mind as long as you follow their design and usability guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the recommended way of using Cordova. See [General Tips](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/security/index.html#use-inappbrowser-for-outside-links)

> Use the InAppBrowser when opening links to any outside website. This is much safer than whitelisting a domain name and including the content directly in your application because the InAppBrowser will use the native browser's security features and will not give the website access to your Cordova environment. Even if you trust the third party website and include it directly in your application, that third party website could link to malicious web content.

The [`<content>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#content)node in the `config.xml` is supposed to be the default HTML page that gets loaded when Cordova first loads. Not an IP address. It should reference an HTML page from your `www` folder.

Comment: So you're saying Cordova no longer supports loading a remote HTML page as the base of the app? This functionality used to work, and I'm confused why this is no longer supported.

Comment: I never said it wasn't supported. There's probably a hack to get around it using an `iframe`, but based on the Cordova documentation, content should be served locally from the device in `/www`. Apps that do what this dev is trying to implement usually get rejected since it is a poor user experience. If you're trying to load a remote site in Cordova, why not just make a mobile website instead?

Comment: @johnborges Pretty much everything you just said is incorrect.  You don't need a hack using an iframe.  Cordova works with external websites just fine. Apps loading external pages are used all over (I myself have published several) and Apple does not reject them unless you violate their UI guidelines.  And you don't always have a choice when it comes to having an app like this.  Why would you assume a developer on stackoverflow is allowed to make business decisions?

As I said in my answer, I think this was a bug in previous versions of Cordova because the current version works properly.

Answer (score -1):

**options 1:**

you can do one thing, inside `www/index.html` put an iframe which opens `http://10.1.1.1:3000`

```
<iframe src="http://10.1.1.1:3000">
   <p>Your device does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

do apply styles to get desired height, width and other options.

**options 2:**

use [inappbrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://10.1.1.1:3000', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

see more options at [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

Comment: Keep in mind when you use the InAppBrowser that the remote site will not be able to take advantage of any Cordova Plugins. I also tend to avoid using `iframes` since they behave somewhat badly on mobile. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage